# Vector of Structs of Vector and String Not printing correctly

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am a beginning c++ student and am attempting to write a program that takes a word in a file and indexes it, listing each word only once and displaying the line numbers of every time that word appears. I have tried using a map but i found it impossible to get the line numbers for the words. Instead, I am using a vector of structs that has an integer vector and a string for each word. I am trying to read each word, place it into a stringstream, then output it into the string in the struct. Then I take the line number and push_back it into the vector in the struct. then I save everything to the vector of the struct and try to print out each word associated with the line number vector. I am getting nowhere and would like some help. Itd be much appreciated! Here is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;



 struct words {
 vector<int> lineNumbers;
 string word;
```

};

```
int main() {
ifstream inFile, testStream;
ofstream outFile; 
string temp, choice, inFileName, outFileName, word, trash, word2, tempString; 
int idx = 0, count = 0, idxTwo = 0;
bool outputOpened = false;
//map <string,int> wordList;    
/map <string,int>::iterator wordIt;     
stringstream myStream(ios_base::in| ios_base::out); 

vector<words> myIndex; 
words data; 



for (;;) {  
    cout << "Options: "<< endl << "1. Index" << endl << "2. Quit" << endl 
    << "Please enter an option: ";
    getline(cin, temp);
    //cin >> temp;
    //cin.ignore(8192, '\n');
    choice.resize(temp.length());
    transform(temp.begin(), temp.end(), choice.begin(), ::toupper);
    if (choice.compare("INDEX") == 0 || choice.compare("1") == 0) {
        do {
            inFileName.clear();
            cout << "Index Program" << endl
            << "==============" << endl << endl;
            cout << "Input file name: ";
            getline(cin, inFileName);
            inFile.open(inFileName.c_str());
            if(inFile.fail()) {
                cout << "Can't open file" << endl;
                if(inFile.bad()) {
                    cout << "Bad" << endl;
                }
                inFile.clear();
            }
        }
        while (!inFile.is_open());
        do {
            cout << "Output file name: ";
            getline( cin, outFileName);
            testStream.clear();
            testStream.open(outFileName.c_str());
            if(testStream.good()) {
                cout << "That file already exists, try again" <<         endl;
                testStream.clear();
                testStream.close();
            }
            else {
                testStream.clear();
                testStream.close();
                outFile.open(outFileName.c_str());
                if (outFile.good()) {
                    outputOpened = true;
                }
            }
        }
        while (!outputOpened);

        while (getline(inFile, trash)){

            count++;
            myStream << trash; 
            //myStream >> tempString; 

            while(myStream >> data.word) {

                data.lineNumbers.push_back(count);
                myIndex.push_back(data);
            }
        }
        for (idx = 0; idx < myIndex.size(); idx++) {
            outFile << "Word: "<< " "<< myIndex[idx].word << ", ";
            for (idxTwo = 0; idxTwo < myIndex[idx].lineNumbers.size(); idxTwo++) {
                outFile << "Found on lines " << " " << myIndex[idx].lineNumbers[idxTwo];
            }
        }
        inFile.close();
        outFile.close();
    }
    else if (choice.compare("QUIT") == 0 || choice.compare("2") == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        cout << temp << " is an unrecognized option, please try again" << endl;
    }
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! What is the actual problem that you're having (error, unexpected behavior, other things)?  All we have is your code and your intentions =)

Comment: Oh sorry! My problem is that it prints each word, but it prints all of the line numbers in a row  and does not come close to separating which word goes with which lines. It will say something like word1 1 word2 1,2 word3 1,2,3 etc.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Feel free to edit that into your question body (using the "edit" button right below the question) so people can quickly see what the problem is.  Good luck in your studies =)

Comment: So can anyone help me get going again? Any push in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

For this part of your program:

```
    while (getline(inFile, trash)){
        count++;
        myStream << trash; 
        //myStream >> tempString; 
        while(myStream >> data.word) {
            // 2.
            // data.lineNumbers.clear();
            data.lineNumbers.push_back(count);
            myIndex.push_back(data);
        }
        // 1. add:
        // myStream.clear();
    }
```

1. You are using a global `myStream`. But the state of this `myStream` will be in a bad state after processing each line, as it ran out of data. The state mush be cleared for it to work again.
2. The `data` is also global, which make the line number for every word to be saved in `data.lineNumber`, not only the line number of the current word. You may want to clear it at each run.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you are always appending each word to the `vector<words>`.

What you probably want, is a `map<string, vector<int>>`. Use .insert to insert words in to the set, if it already exists then just append the current line number to the value.

Comment: I would just like to say that I ended up doing the map and it worked great! I wasn't aware that maps could have a vector in them. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some issues:

Add `myStream.clear();` after the `while(myStream >> data.word)` loop.

Add "\n" to the end of the following line to print on a new line:

```
outFile << "Found on lines " << " " << myIndex[idx].lineNumbers[idxTwo]<<"\n";
```

Also, the following nested loop will not give you correct results. It will grow with line numbers and keep printing "Found on lines":

```
for (idx = 0; idx < myIndex.size(); idx++) {
outFile << "Word: "<< " "<< myIndex[idx].word << ", ";
  for (idxTwo = 0; idxTwo < myIndex[idx].lineNumbers.size(); idxTwo++) {
     outFile << "Found on lines " << " " << myIndex[idx].lineNumbers[idxTwo]<<"\n";
    }
```